# CSS styles do not apply consistently on Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I have some sort of a accordion menu

```
   <div class="grid-item-1">
      <div class="title">Category title 1</div>
      <a class="option1">Item 1</a>
      <a class="option2">Item 2</a>
   </div>
   <div class="grid-item-2">
      <div class="title">Category title 2</div>
      <a class="option1">Item 1</a>
      <a class="option2">Item 2</a>
   </div>
```

So basically how this works is that both **Category title 1** and **Category title 2** are visible and **Item 1** and **Item 2** both have style

```
display: none
```

applied. When I click on **Category title 1** js applies .active on

```
<div class="title">Category title 1</div>
```

which applies `display:none` on it. I also have a style

```
.grid-item-1.title.active a{
    display: block;
}
```

and the problem is that on an emulator everything works fine, but on an actual Android device this options do not appear consistently, sometimes the style is applied and sometimes it don't and I can't find the source of this problem. Has anyone experienced the same problems and is there any solution to it?

Comment: Hard to say without a working example (in a sandbox). Although, this last `display: block` style doesn't do anything, as there is no `<a>` child inside `.title`. Maybe you mean `grid-item-1.title.active ~ a { ... }` which selects siblings `<a>` siblings of `.title` component

Comment: @TomaszGolinsky Sorry the actual layout is a bit more complicated so I had to simplify it, I ment that .active is aplied on `grid-item-1 ` and `div title` is being hidden and `a option-1` and `a option-2` are being shown. My main concern is that there is no consistency in this bug occurance